# How to pass value from option select to url in button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this simple PayPal "Add to Cart" form and below it an express checkout button "Buy Now".

```
<form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<select name="quantity" id="QuantitySelect">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="abc">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="22.99">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<button>Add to Cart</button>
</form>
```

How do I pass **quantity** value from this form into the 'Buy Now' button?

```
<button id="buynow" onclick="location.href='https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&currency_code=USD&item_name=abc&amount=22.99&quantity='">Buy Now</button>
```

I'm looking for Javascript or jQuery solution. Whichever uses least amount of code.

Comment: You can get the value of the quantity with `document.getElementById('QuantitySelect').value`

Comment: Or even shorter with `QuantitySelect.value`.

Comment: I answered my own question an hour later. Check below my solution. Let me know if it's ok. It works.

Answer (score 0):

In your `onclick` handler you need to call a function that both updates your url, and redirects you via `location.href`. A simple function like this works:

```
function updateLocationLink() {
  var quantity = QuantitySelect.value;
  alert('https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&currency_code=USD&item_name=abc&amount=22.99&quantity='+quantity);
}
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/nL0v6sz3/5/

Answer (score 0):

Don't use inline event handlers, it's widely considered really bad practice.

Instead, use `addEventListener()`:

```js
addtocart.addEventListener('click', function() {
  buynow.dataset.url = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&currency_code=USD&item_name=abc&amount=22.99&quantity=" + QuantitySelect.value;
})

buynow.addEventListener('click', function() {
  window.location.href = buynow.dataset.url
})
```

```html
<select name="quantity" id="QuantitySelect">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="abc">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="22.99">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<button id="addtocart">Add to Cart </button>
<button id="buynow" data-url="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&currency_code=USD&item_name=abc&amount=22.99&quantity=">Buy Now</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for help. Actually I ended up answering my own question. This is how I did it

```
<button id="buynow" onclick="location.href='https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&currency_code=USD&item_name=abc&amount=22.99&quantity=' + $('#QuantitySelect option:selected').val();">Buy Now</button>
```

Comment: Sure that works. Please keep the suggestions connexo and I provided in the future. It will become more helpful as you deal with larger `onclick` functions that are more then one line.